# Reduce the heat output of a MOSFET (buck LM5085)

Tags: power, buck, heat

First of all I have to say that I am a beginner, and I don't have an oscilloscope to work with. Just a multimeter.

I'm trying to design a PoE+ board with a 9.5 V @ 3 A output.
The PoE+ part works fine ([schematic](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/eval-board-schematic/DC2093A-2-SCH.PDF)): it outputs 54 V when paired.

The problem is with the buck MOSFET, which gets very hot (about 100°C).

I used WEBENCH Power Designer for this schematic, using a LM5085:
[image: Buck converter 54V to 9.5V3A]

I must also say that I added R20 to the MOSFET gate, which was not on the proposed schematic. With this resistor (100 or 150 ohms) I get the desired power. Without, the voltage is good but there is no current. My charge doesn't load. With it, the current is correct but the MOSFET gets really hot.

So my 2 questions:

- Am I right to add this R20 resistor?
- And if so, how can I reduce the heat generated by the MOSFET? (My PCB is already well cooled.)

I've already been able to reduce R20 by increasing the C18 capacitor (33 uF replaced by 150 uF), but it still heats up too much.

Answer (score 1):

To reduce the heat generated in a MOSFET you typically do one or more of the following:

- Select a MOSFET with a lower RDSon (at the voltage you will be driving it)
- Select a MOSFET with a lower VGS threshold
- Lower the switching frequency
- Drive the gate harder

You will notice that most of this is to avoid spending too much time in the ohmic region of operation, where most of your heat is being generated.

Since your device is a fixed on-time type, changing frequency isn't going to happen without re-design.

The gate resistor is slowing down your switching, so reduce it or figure out why your circuit doesn't work without it.  Is the gate capacitance on that MOSFET really high?

It may be easiest to select a better MOSFET.

Comment: Thanks. Indeed, the recommended mofset was out of stock. I tried to find a match, maybe I'll look another one, or modify the frequency.

Comment: It looks like you have replaced the MOSFET with one that has 4 times the RDSon of the one recommended.  This could definitely be your problem.

Comment: LM5085 switching frequency can be adjusted by changing Rt value!